# unexpected EOF whilst parsing error in python

Tags: python

```
swim_length =int(input("Please enter a swim length: "))

while swim_length < 0:
print("The length has to be a positive number")
swim_length=int(input("Please enter a positive number: ")
```

Hi could anyone help me with this, im sure i made a simple mistake but i can't figure out where exactly.

Comment: you're missing a `)` at the end of last line

Answer (score 2):

You have to add indentation to while loop and parentheses to the end of the last line:

```
swim_length =int(input("Please enter a swim length: "))

while swim_length < 0:
    print("The length has to be a positive number")
    swim_length=int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

first in the last line you are misssing an ending )

```
swim_length=int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
```

also the body of the while loop needs to be indented

```
while swim_length < 0:
    print("The length has to be a positive number")
    swim_length=int(input("Please enter a positive number: ")
```